# Gtk compile with another library

Tags: c, gtk

I'm have a program using gtk3 library and I want to add another library (portsf).
I'm compiling the file with this command :

```
` gcc -lm -lportsf -o sp SProcess.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0`
```

It's working perfectly but when I add -lportsf like this :

```
 gcc -lm -lportsf -o sproc SProcess.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0`
```

I have multiples error :

```
SProcess.c:(.text+0x81): référence indéfinie vers « psf_init »
SProcess.c:(.text+0x92): référence indéfinie vers « psf_sndOpen »
...
```

(réference indéfinie is french for undefined reference and psf_init and psf_sndOpen are functions of portsf library)
I dont understand why I have these errors because when I compile a simple program using portsf (withou gtk) it works :

```
gcc portsf_t.c -lportsf -lm -o test
```

`

Comment: There's no difference between the first and second lines in your post. Regardless, I understand what's going on: gcc (and other linkers) require you to specify dependencies *after* dependents. You have to say `-lportsf` *after* `portsf_t.c`, and the `pkg-config` for GTK+ also must be after `portsf_t.c`.

Comment: working perfectly, thanks you